# the logic here doesn't make sense in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
cellColor = {};
cellColor['cel32'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel24'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel16'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel8'] = 'blue';

console.log(
  (((cellColor['cel32'] === cellColor['cel24']) === cellColor['cel16']) ==
    cellColor['cel8']) ==
  'blue',
);
```

//the output is false here why?

Comment: Because `true === 'blue'` is false

Comment: for a little bit of clarification: a === b yields true, which is then compared to c (blue), yielding false, again being compared to d (also blue), again returning false… in mathematics, this is valid notation. in most programming languages, when comparing, you’re evaluating functions in sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `boolean` with `blue` so that will return `false`

you are comparing `true` with `blue` which will return `false`.

```
cellColor = {};
cellColor['cel32'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel24'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel16'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel8'] = 'blue';

const a = cellColor['cel32'] === cellColor['cel24'];
console.log(a); // true

const b = cellColor['cel16'];
// Here a is true and b is blue
const c = a === b;
console.log(c); // true is not equal to 'blue' so return false

// Here c is false and cellColor['cel8'] is blue
const d = c === cellColor['cel8'];
console.log(d); // false is not equal to 'blue' so return false

const e = d === 'blue';
console.log(e);// false is not equal to 'blue' so return false
```

```js
cellColor = {};
cellColor['cel32'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel24'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel16'] = 'blue';
cellColor['cel8'] = 'blue';

const a = cellColor['cel32'] === cellColor['cel24'];
console.log(a); // true

const b = cellColor['cel16'];
const c = a === b;
console.log(c); // true is not equal to 'blue' so return false

const d = c === cellColor['cel8'];
console.log(d); // false is not equal to 'blue' so return false

const e = d === 'blue';
console.log(e);// false is not equal to 'blue' so return false
```